# C# .NET Passing dynamic <T> in method

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

Here's what I'm trying to do.

Class1 : baseclass

```
    private void Update()
    {
       base.Update(Updated);
    }

    private void Updated(IRestResponse<thisClass> response)
    { 
        ....
    }
```

...

baseclass:

```
public void Update(<T> callback)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com");
        client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(App.AuthenticationResult.access_token);
        var request = new RestRequest(path, Method.GET);
        client.ExecuteAsync<...T...>(request, callback);
    }
```

Essentially I'm looking to be able to reuse Update in the baseclass in multiple classes that follow the same structure.

Comment: just as a clarification point this is called generic <T> not dynamic (which has another meaning in c#)

Answer (score 0):

Currently your baseclass `Update` method has some syntax errors.

```
public void Update<T>(T callback)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com");
    client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(App.AuthenticationResult.access_token);
    var request = new RestRequest(path, Method.GET);
    client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, callback);
}
```

If the parameter is a callback shouldn't it be a delegate?

It doesn't need to be this generic but you could do something like this:

```
public delegate T CallbackDelegate<T>();
public void Update<T>(CallbackDelegate<T> callback)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com");
        client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(App.AuthenticationResult.access_token);
        var request = new RestRequest(path, Method.GET);
        client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, callback);
    }
```

Comment: I can supply client.ExecuteAsync<ClassName>(request, functionName); and it works just fine.. I'm just trying to supply the callback function to the function parameter, and the type to use in the ExecuteAsync<...>...

Comment: Shouldn't the callback parameter in ExecuteAsync be `callback` not `Updated`?

Comment: I don't know enough about why this isn't working to really clarify..

Updated is a method in the base class, and it works just fine.

Once I supply a function as a parameter for the Update() function, nothing makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

What I gather from your question is that you want to share/reuse `Update()` but have a custom `Updated()` in the extending class...?

Probably the easiest way to do that is to create a virtual method in the base class that is overridden in the extending class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Updated() { }
    public void Update()
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com");
        client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(App.AuthenticationResult.access_token);
        var request = new RestRequest(path, Method.GET);

        //implement whatever logic you want with the response.

        this.Updated(); //include whatever parameters you need to pass.
    }
}

public class Class1 : BaseClass
{
    public override void Updated()
    {
        //implement logic specific to Class1...
    }
}
```